# Tomcat restart throws error regarding the missing destroy() method

Tags: tomcat, servlet-filters

My service is deployed on tomcat. Recently we upgraded the tomcat to 9.0.43. And when the service is restarted (tomcat is installed on windows as a service), it throws the following error:

```
SEVERE [Thread-19] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release Failed to destroy the filter named [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter] of type [org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter]
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract destroy()V of interface javax.servlet.Filter.
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:301)
```

I looked into and find the root cause. Earlier there was a **destroy** method implementation in **tomcat-websocket.jar** in the WsFilter.class under
lib\tomcat-websocket\org\apache\tomcat\websocket\server\WsFilter.class, which is now missing.

*How shall I proceed now? Any ideas?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Servlet 4.0 API the `init` and `close` methods of the [`Filter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) interface have default implementations. Check if you are not deploying another (and older) `javax.servlet-api.jar` with your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me check my project and get back.

Comment: I couldn't find anything. The libraries only contains the tomcat 9.0.41 libs.

Comment: There should be a `javax.servlet.Filter` in `$CATALINA_BASE/lib/servlet-api.jar`, while the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of each application should not contain any JAR containing that class.

Comment: Nope there are only 2 jars deployed under WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Some libraries like to include files that don't belong to them. I would check with `zip -t` at this point. The old `javax.servlet.Filter` class must be loaded from somewhere, most probably the web application classloader.

Comment: I got it . There is a servlet api in another folder but seems like it is being picked up. Thanks a lot for the answer. I will mark is as answer. I will check for the classpath  issue.

Comment: Maybe you have a [CATALINA_BASE/CATALINA_HOME](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/introduction.html#CATALINA_HOME_and_CATALINA_BASE) configuration. Look into `catalina.properties` to see the classpath's of all Tomcat classloaders.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66480830/tomcat-picking-up-servlet-api-jar-from-shared-folder-instead-of-tomcat-lib-folde

Comment: Can you please check this question as well?